# Postgres save incoming data

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to save incoming data from d in postgres database but it keeps returning listdata has no attribute data and I don't understand why - if I'm not mistaken, there is only one column that needs to be saved right?

If you do `print(d)` you can see the data coming but I don't know how to save it.

```
from datetime import datetime
from requests import Session
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psycopg2
import time
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

page_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/equity?symbol=LT"
chart_data_url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/chart-databyindex"

s= Session()

h = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
     "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    }

s.headers.update(h)
r = s.get(page_url)
def fetch_data(symbol):
    data = {"index": symbol + "EQN"}
    r = s.get(chart_data_url, params=data)
    data = r.json()['grapthData']
    return [[datetime.utcfromtimestamp(d[0]/1000),d[1]] for d in data]

data = fetch_data("MARUTI")
with psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="tickdata",
    port="5432",
    user="postgres",
    password="passkey",
    cursor_factory=RealDictCursor,
) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql = """INSERT INTO pytick (sequence) VALUES (%s) RETURNING *"""
        
        cur.executemany(sql, data)
```

> returning this error
> cur.executemany(sql, data)
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
> [Finished in 1.8s]

Comment: Indentation looks weird (`d = fetch_data(...` is at same level as a `return `statement`...) and indentation does matter in Python. Could you please provide correct indentation?

Comment: reformatted check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sqlcode` is a tuple. It probably shouldn't be.

You're also not using the `RETURNING` clause, so get rid of it.

All in all, you're maybe looking for something like

```
data = fetch_data("MARUTI")
with psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="tickdata",
    port="5432",
    user="postgres",
    password="passkey",
    cursor_factory=RealDictCursor,
) as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql = "INSERT INTO pytick (id, data) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cur.executemany(sql, data)
```

to insert all of the 2-tuples in `data`.

Comment: i am getting this error::: not all arguments formatted during string formatting

Comment: Where are you getting that error?

Comment: cur.executemany(sql,data) here I am getting that error ,i've excluded that id field

Comment: see i have updated the code

Comment: Well why did you remove the id field? Your `data` has 2 items per inserted row.

Comment: its giving integer datatype error

Comment: can you tell the data types of incoming data because problem is lying at there i guess , one is sequence and other is time? or if i give varchar format then what will be the code? because data ,has the format varchar

Comment: if i go with my previous code AKX then i am getting this issue ,,,,                           cur.executemany(sql, data)
psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type timestamp without time zone
LINE 1: INSERT INTO pytick (id,data) VALUES ('2022-01-10T09:15:00'::...
                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: hey i have finished and its successfully run

Comment: data type error was in database